# Linux xsetwacom setting equivalent to Windows wacom driver mapping

Tags: drivers

In the Windows drivers for Wacom tablets, you have the option of mapping (a) the hole monitor to a specific area of the tablet, something like the picture in this link:

[image]

I can't find an option in the xsetwacom command to emulate this behavior. Is this posible?